# Character apparently doesn't get translated to its ASCII value in a C kernel

Tags: c, osdev, freestanding

I'm developing a basic C kernel in a Kali machine and testing it inside QEMU. This is the kernel code:

```
void kernel_main();
void print();

void print() {
    char* vidMem = (char*)0xb8000;
    *vidMem = "A";
    vidMem++;
    *vidMem = 0x0f;
}

void entry() {
    kernel_main();
    while(1);
}

void kernel_main() {
    print();
}
```

This prints `Z` instead of `A`, but if I replace `"A"` with the ASCII value for `A`, `0x41`, it works as expected and prints `A` to the screen. Additionally, I also get this error:

```
kernel.c:6:10: warning: assignment to 'char' from 'char *' makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
    6 |  *vidMem = "A";
      |          ^
```

If I understand it correctly, the compiler thinks I'm trying to change the value of `vidMem` itself to a different value of a different data type; however, I'm dereferencing the `vidMem` variable and only changing the byte of memory pointed to by `vidMem`, so I'm confused as to why I get this error. I don't get the error when I replace `"A"` with `0x41`, so all I see is the compiler is treating `"A"` and `0x41` differently. Why is that and how can I print a character I want without needing to provide its ASCII value?

Comment: No, the compiler error does not say what you think it does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
*vidMem = "A";
```

This is equivalent to

```
vidMem[0] = "A";
```

"A" is a string, not a character, so you're assigning (the lowest byte of) the address of the string `"A"` into that memory position.

You want to do:

```
vidMem[0] = 'A';
```

Note the single quotes, which makes it a `char` literal.